# Connecting to two databases in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I can connect the databases in my project created by Laravel 5, but I use this code.

Is there any way to add `User::all()` before that `->select("select * from users");`?

```
public function index(){
    $user = \DB::connection('nombrebd')->select("select * from users");
    $user2 = \DB::connection('nombrebd2')->select("select * from users");
    return $user+$user2;    
}
```

**UPDATE**

Sorry for my bad explanation   , I need to receive all information about user in two differents databases.

Comment: You should better describe what you want to do. Code `->select("select * from users");` is there twice, so it's not clear where you want to add it.

Comment: I update the question @DawidFerenczy

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to use Eloquent as the base of your query to avoid writing actual SQL statements, you can do the following to get all users from each database:

```
$user = App::make('App\User')->setConnection('nombrebd')->get();
$user2 = App::make('App\User')->setConnection('nombrebd2')->get();
```

You can't use `User::all()` as you'd like, because that initialises a query builder instance and fetches the results all in one go, so there is no way to specify which connection it should use.

Answer (score 0):

You could have two models, and in one of them you can specify an alternate connection:

```
protected $connection = 'mysql-alt';
```

Once you query both models, you can even merge them as such:

```
$users = $user_list_a->merge($user_list_b);
```

I use this approach when dealing with legacy databases.

Comment: Which this solution , if I have more than two databases I have problem to created a model for db @user2094178